# magento 2.3 how to override protected function in custom module

Tags: magento2.3.1, sitemaps, override-model

I want to override protected method _prepareProduct present in vendor/magento/module-sitemap/Model/ResourceModel/Catalog/Product.php in my custom module.

I have overridden the Model file by adding preference in di.xml but it's not working.

Still, the default model is working. 
I have done di:compile and setup upgrade too. There is no error showing.

Please provide a solution to override this.

Thanks!

Comment: can u write here your full code?

Comment: @chanchal ,why you deleting the question again again?

Comment: @AmitBera Because the issue was there is a third party module present which has already overridden the same file. That's why it was not overriding mine.
Now, I have overridden the third-party module file.

Answer (score 2):

Your **di.xml** code will be look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sitemap\Model\ResourceModel\Catalog\Product" type="{Vendorname}\{Modulename}\Rewrite\Magento\Sitemap\Model\ResourceModel\Catalog\Product"/>
</config>
```

**And Rewrite class code:**

```
<?php
namespace {Vendorname}\{Modulename}\Rewrite\Magento\Sitemap\Model\ResourceModel\Catalog;

class Product extends \Magento\Sitemap\Model\ResourceModel\Catalog\Product
{
    protected function _prepareProduct(array $productRow, $storeId)
    {
    // Do changes at here
        $product = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();

        $product['id'] = $productRow[$this->getIdFieldName()];
        if (empty($productRow['url'])) {
            $productRow['url'] = 'catalog/product/view/id/' . $product->getId();
        }
        $product->addData($productRow);
        $this->_loadProductImages($product, $storeId);

        return $product;
    }
}
```

Comment: public function getCollection($storeId) Getting error in this function

Comment: Notice: Undefined property: {{}}o\Sitemap\Model\ResourceModel\Catalog\Product::$connection in

Comment: Can you please help me

Comment: use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product as HelperProduct;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image\UrlBuilder;
use Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlRewriteGenerator;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class Product extends \Magento\Sitemap\Model\ResourceModel\Catalog\Product 
{
}

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/367897/getting-error-after-overwrite-core-file-of-sitemap-module-magento2