# Getting error after overwrite core file of sitemap module. magento2

Tags: magento2, overrides, resource-model, override-model

I have successfully overwrite core file: **Magento\Sitemap\Model\ResourceModel\Catalog\Product**

but getting error in **public function getCollection($storeId)** for this: **$this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag and $this->getConnection()** method not found.

When try to overwrite whole file getting this error:
**Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Sitemap\Helper\Data. Actual type: string;**

Ref: I have overwrite core file as this:
**[magento 2.3 how to override protected function in custom module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/290816/magento-2-3-how-to-override-protected-function-in-custom-module)**

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Please add your file and DI.xml in the question

Comment: Can you please add a Magento version?

Answer (score 1):

Update your override file's `parent::__construct` with below:

```
parent::__construct($context, $sitemapData, $productResource, $storeManager, $productVisibility, $productStatus, $mediaGalleryResourceModel, $mediaGalleryReadHandler,$mediaConfig, $connectionName, $productModel, $catalogImageHelper, $scopeConfig, $urlBuilder);
```

**Now run** `php bin/magento s:d:c`